# How to receive a notification every hour if a condition is met on android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Okay, I know my title can be confusing so I'll explain a bit. I have access to an API and I would like that: **every hour**, my application, in the **background**, makes a request to this API and sends a **notification** if the API response contains a more or less recent date. To check if the answer is recent, I am already able to do it but what I would like to know is how to make this request in the background every hour and then how to send the data of this request in a notification (I already know how to create a notification, that's not the problem). I'm stuck for some time, I imagine that the answer will be something related to a **server**, a domain that I know absolutely nothing about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver with the repeating time 1 hour

**Example:**

```
val flag = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        } else PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

val intent = Intent(context, YourReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, flag)
val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager

alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC,
        timeInMillis,
        1000 * 60 * 60, //1h in millis
        pendingIntent
    )
```

Then write your YourReceiver and override onReceive function

```
class YourReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        //call api & check your requirements then push notification
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application>
...
    <receiver android:name=".YourReceiver" />
</application>
```

Or you can try **periodic work request**:
https://medium.com/@sumon.v0.0/android-jetpack-workmanager-onetime-and-periodic-work-request-94ace224ff7d

Answer (score 0):

If the API already exists, you don't need a server.  You just need to schedule a job to be done on the device every hour.  You can use WorkScheduler for that.  If the API needs to be written, then yes you need a server and need to learn how to write a web service.  But that's well beyond the size of a stack overflow question, you can google for a variety of tutorials on that.